# Search bar text getting covered due to search icon

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, frontend

I want to put my search icon on the left side of the search bar as below:

[image]

But when i am trying to do so, the search bar text gets covered under the icon as shown below:
[image]

How do i ensure that the text starts after the icon?

Comment: show your code or live example. you can do this by adding padding on input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `padding-left` property to the input box with appropriate amount of pixels.

```css
.foo
{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="foo" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
```